# How to provide training data to TF_SessionRun from [c_api.h]

Tags: python, c, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I am trying to implement the training part of the [fashion-mnist](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/basic_classification) tutorial using TF 2.0beta C api(c_api.h).

Briefly, model is created using python following the previously mentioned tutorial. The model is then saved as a .pb file which is then loaded in my C program together with the training data (28*28 grayscale images) and training labels (scalars ranging from [0-9]).

As some of you may know, the TF C api has poor documentation (insert rant full of frustration [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/9rl7yh/motherfucking_opensource_tensorflow_shit_makes_it/)) and after much reading and searching on the internet [here](https://gist.github.com/asimshankar/7c9f8a9b04323e93bb217109da8c7ad2#file-train-c), [here](https://medium.com/@vladislavsd/undocumented-tensorflow-c-api-b527c0b4ef6), [here](https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f), and [here](https://github.com/Neargye/hello_tf_c_api) among many other places, I am still unable to achieve this task (more details down below).

## So let's get started:

I don't want to drown this question in code, but I want you to be able to access what I have done already.

The python [script](https://gist.github.com/7PintsOfCherryGarcia/094e68585be228e42efc5764a97ab5d7) that generates the model saves it via:
keras.experimental.export_saved_model.

To execute the code simply:
python3 [createModel.py](https://gist.github.com/7PintsOfCherryGarcia/094e68585be228e42efc5764a97ab5d7).

Saved model will be stored in a new folder called "saved_model". **This is important as this name is hard coded in the C code**

[Data](https://gist.github.com/7PintsOfCherryGarcia/455370c9550a6c5c10f9135155a8b282) for training the model is obtained via python TF as well.

Again: python [getData.py](https://gist.github.com/7PintsOfCherryGarcia/455370c9550a6c5c10f9135155a8b282).

Saving the data and corresponding labels as data.txt and labels.txt **Again, these names are important as they are hard coded in my C code**

## Now we can move into C code!!

All code resides in a [single](https://gist.github.com/7PintsOfCherryGarcia/407a0c115dd1eccb4ae78dc935dd4b71) file with as much commenting as I imagined was necessary. Compilation should be straight forward as long as you have libtensorflow.so.2 and libtensorflow_framework.so.2.0.0

`gcc -Wall -I /path/to/TFlib/include -L /path/to/TFlib/lib -o trainMnist trainMnist.c`

In an x86_64 system there should be no warnings (At least in the two computers I have tried)

After compilation execute with:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/TFlib/lib ./trainMnist`

You can skip LD_LIBRARY_PATH if the .so files are already reachable.

If you don't have the TF shared object files I would gladly share them with anybody if you dare to trust compiled code from some random person. You can generate it yourself with:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
git checkout r2.0
./configure
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:libtensorflow
```

header and .so files will be in bazel-bin/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/libtensorflow.tar.gz

Assuming `saved_model`, `data.txt`, and `labels.txt` are in the same directory as where ./trainMnist is ran, only TF warnings should be printed and some verbose messages from the code itself.

but the function of interest is:

```c
int Belly_ModelTrain(model_t *model,
                     float **train_data,
                     float **label_data,
                     int numPoints)
```

`model` is a struct that holds important members to start a TF session

`train_data` holds numPoints arrays of 28*28=784 floats (pixel values of images)

`label_data` holds numPoints arrays of 10 floats (all 0 except the true label for that image).

`numPoints` is the number of images that are loaded. The value of `numPoints` is hard coded in main.

In this function training occurs in the following way:

```c
  // The actual tensors that will hold the data and be passed to TF_SessionRun
  TF_Tensor *x, *y;
  
  // Establish the dimentions of the input data
  const int64_t dimTrain[] = {numPoints, 784}; //pixel values
  const int64_t dimLabel[] = {numPoints, 10};  //labels
  
  {
  //Boilerplate allocation code happens here 
  size_t nbytesT = (numPoints*784) * sizeof(float);
  x = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, dimTrain, 2, nbytesT);

  size_t nbytesL = (numPoints*10) * sizeof(float);
  y = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, dimLabel, 2, nbytesL);
  }
  
  //Copy the data in my arrays to the tensors
  memcpy(TF_TensorData(x), train_data, nbytesT);
  memcpy(TF_TensorData(y), label_data, nbytesL);

  //TBH I really don't know what is going on in these two lines
  //Establish model inputs and model targets(labels)
  TF_Output inputs[2] = {model->input, model->target};
  TF_Tensor* input_values[2] = {x, y};
  //training operation defined in model
  const TF_Operation* train_op[1] = {model->train_op};

  //Run the model with the data
  TF_SessionRun(model->session,
                NULL,
                inputs, input_values, 2,
                NULL, NULL, 0,
                train_op, 1,
                NULL, model->status);
 
  TF_DeleteTensor(x);
  TF_DeleteTensor(y);
  //Return 0 on success
  return Belly_CheckStatus(model->status);
```

I expect this function to run nicely and return 0 based on the status of the model which should be TF_OK. This of course fails and I get:

## ERROR: Node 'dense_2_target' (type: 'Placeholder', num of outputs: 1) does not have output [some crazy batshit number]

From the error message I understand my `target` input is misshaped. I have tried changing the way I pass `label_data` as well as changing `dimL` without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was still thinking in python while working with the C api.

In [trainMnist.c](https://gist.github.com/7PintsOfCherryGarcia/407a0c115dd1eccb4ae78dc935dd4b71) data is being read into an array of arrays (float **points):

```c
int Belly_ReadData(float **points, int numSamples) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  for(int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
    //Allocate memory for datapoint
    points[i] = (float *)malloc(784*sizeof(float));
  ...
  ...
  ...
    //Read other 783 pixels
    for(int j = 0; j < 783; j++) {
      point = strtok(NULL,"\t");
      points[i][j+1] = strtof(point,&err);
      if(*err != 0) return -1;
    }
  ...
  }
}
```

Afterwards this array of arrays is fed into the input tensor "x" in:

```c
int Belly_ModelTrain(model_t *model,
                     float **train_data,
                     float **label_data,
                     int numPoints) {
  ...
  ...
  ...

  // Allocate data for tensors
  x = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, dimTrain, 2, nbytesT);
  if(x==NULL) {
    printf("ERROR allocate x\n");
    return -1;
  }

  y = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, dimLabel, 2, nbytesL);
  if(y==NULL) {
    printf("ERROR allocate y\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Copy data from arrays into tensors
  memcpy(TF_TensorData(x), train_data, nbytesT); //<===== "train_data should be an array of floats"
  memcpy(TF_TensorData(y), label_data, nbytesL); //<===== "label_data should be an array of floats"
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

So effectively the way I understand it, I was passing garbage data into both tensors x and y.

Will post corrected code for anybody who wants to try it.